# What's the difference between ANN, SVM and KNN classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, svm, knn

I am doing remote sensing image classification. I am using the object-oriented method: first I segmented the image to different regions, then I extract the features from regions such as color, shape and texture. The number of all features in a region may be 30 and commonly there are 2000 regions in all, and I will choose 5 classes with 15 samples for every class.

In summary:

- Sample data 1530
- Test data 197530

How do I choose the proper classifier? If there are 3 classifiers (ANN, SVM, and KNN), which should I choose for better classification?

Comment: Why don't you just try all three methods and choose the one that works the best?  OpenCV includes all of the classifiers you mentioned plus a few more...

Comment: What toolset / language are you using ? SGDClassifier in scikits.learn, is fast, see [libsvm-training-very-slow-on-100k-rows-suggestions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14893/libsvm-training-very-slow-on-100k-rows-suggestions), but it sounds as though you want simplicity not speed. In any case, start small.

Comment: jeff7 ,your suggestion is good ,but i want to get some theory answers !

Comment: If you want to talk theory, you'd do better on [CompSci](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "sample data" is the train set, it seems very small. I'd first suggest using more than 15 examples per class.

As said in the comments, it's best to match the algorithm to the problem, so you can simply test to see which algorithm works better. But to start with, I'd suggest SVM: it works better than KNN with small train sets, and generally easier to train then ANN, as there are less choices to make.

Comment: but there are only 2000 datas in all . if i choose more than 15 examples per class , is it proper ?

Comment: According to your question, each instance has 2000 regions * 30 features/region = 60000 features. 15 cases to learn from are defiantly a small number... Do you have 2000 tagged instances (i.e., for which you know the correct class)? if so, why not use most of them (say 60-70%) for training?

Comment: because what i do is remote image classification ,after the ssegmentation of image in first , if i choose more than 15， it will a big examples youy know !

Answer (score 8):

KNN is the most basic machine learning algorithm to paramtise and implement, but as alluded to by @etov, would likely be outperformed by SVM due to the small training data sizes. ANNs have been observed to be limited by insufficient training data also. However, KNN makes the least number of assumptions regarding your data, other than that accurate training data should form relatively discrete clusters.  ANN and SVM are notoriously difficult to paramtise, especially if you wish to repeat the process using multiple datasets and rely upon certain assumptions, such as that your data is linearly separable (SVM).

I would also recommend the Random Forests algorithm as this is easy to implement and is relatively insensitive to training data size, but I would advise against using very small training data sizes.

The scikit-learn module contains these algorithms and is able to cope with large training data sizes, so you could increase the number of training data samples. the best way to know for sure would be to investigate them yourself, as suggested by @etov

Comment: Note that SVM is usually used with non-linear kernels (e.g. radial basis), so the assumption about linear separability is almost never an obstacle. Anyway, +1, random forest are indeed a good alternative here.